Symfony 6.4 - custom_authenticator not taking the access_control
I have a problem with the access_control configuration on a Symfony 6.4 project.
The custom_authenticator I defined does not seem to take the access_control entries into account.
Indeed, all the routes in the project are subject to this authentication.
The routes seem to be correctly defined because when using another firewall (e.g form_login), everything works correctly.
Here is the security.yml file.
security:
    password_hashers:
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\PasswordAuthenticatedUserInterface: 'auto'

    providers:
        app_user_provider:
            id: App\Security\UserProvider

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            lazy: true
            logout:
                path: app_logout

        # this authenticator forces the user to be logged in for every page (even the ones declared as public in access_control)
           # custom_authenticators:
           #    - App\Security\CustomAuthenticator

        # this one works fine
            form_login:
                login_path: app_login
                check_path: app_login


    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$, roles: PUBLIC_ACCESS }


What I want to achieve is :

when an anonymous user access '/' => display the page
when a logged-in user try to access '/' => he should be redirected.

This means I need to know if he's logged in or not (so an exception in the firewall is not a solution)

I created a dummy projet in github to reproduce the problem (https://github.com/mattbild/sf-issue) .
Thanks to anyone who can give me a hand because I can't see what the issue is.
